how to mount a file with path dynamically computed in container for vscode
Using vscode, I have a devcontainer.json similar to
{
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": ".."
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--mount",
        "type=bind,source=$(bash -c 'voms-proxy-info -path'),target=/tmp/x509up_user,readonly"
    ]
// ...
}

on the host the command voms-proxy-info -path returns an absolute path of a file existing on the host machine. I want that file to be mounted in the container. When asking to vscode to "reopen in the container", I get an error
[2024-11-22T10:00:48.640Z] docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '$(bash -c 'voms-proxy-info -path')' mount path must be absolute.

It seems the command is not executed. How to solve this?
I also tried to
{
  "initializeCommand": "export MYVAR=`voms-proxy-info -path`",
  "runArgs": [
        "--mount",
        "type=bind,source=$MYVAR,target=/tmp/x509up_user,readonly"
    ]
// ...
}

but it seems the variable is empty.

If a main goal of your process is to interact with host files, it's often easier to run it directly on the host system.  What tool do you need for development that's hard to directly install?

The point is that I want everybody developing the code to have the same environment with only one click.
